Understanding logic of npm global installed packages and GitLab pipelines
I'm currently trying to use CI/CD in GitLab in one of my projects. However I'm facing some difficulties understanding the logic for npm installed packages globally and how to propagate the installation to other stages in the GitLab pipeline.
I've tried to install a npm package globally but in the following jobs/stages I get an error of command not found.
.gitlab-ci.yml:
image: node:latest

stages:
  - install
  - version

install_dependencies:
  stage: install
  script:
    - npm install -g somepackage

check_version:
  stage: version
  script:
    - somepackage --version

I also tried to use before_scripts to install the npm package globally but this means that in every stage/job the installation will run which also doesn't seem right to me, since I'm repeating the same command unnecessarily.
image: node:latest

stages:
  - version

before_script:
  - npm install -g somepackage

check_version:
  stage: version
  script:
    - somepackage --version

Is before_script the right solution when installing globally? Or should I be using something else to propagate the installation to other stages? Something like cache?

Each stage happens in a clean environment, a fresh container. There's no "global install"; they may not even be running on the same physical host.
